# Qt convert unicode entities

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-studio-2012, unicode

In QT 5.4 and C++ I try to decode a string that has unicode entities.

I have this QString:

```
QString string = "file\u00d6\u00c7\u015e\u0130\u011e\u00dc\u0130\u00e7\u00f6\u015fi\u011f\u00fc\u0131.txt";
```

I want to convert this string to this: `fileÖÇŞİĞÜİçöşiğüı.txt`

I tried `QString`'s `toUtf8` and `fromUtf8` methods. Also tried to decode it character by character.

Is there a way to convert it by using Qt?

Comment: Probably your console is not configured to print Unicode. If you are executing on Windows Prompt, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app

Comment: Thank you. Yes windows console also has unicode problems, but I need to decode it in my cpp codes.

Comment: Your string literal contains Unicode escapes, characters which probably won't fit in 8 bits. And on al Qt platforms, `char` is 8 bits. You'll probably need a wide literal: `L"file\u00d6\u00c7\u015e\u0130..."`

Comment: offtopic: for me this string looks like something what should be a application configuration setting and not hard-coded.

Answer (score 7):

Qt provides a macro called [QStringLiteral](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral) for handling string literals correctly.

Here's a full working example:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main(void) {
   QString string = QStringLiteral("file\u00d6\u00c7\u015e\u0130\u011e\u00dc\u0130\u00e7\u00f6\u015fi\u011f\u00fc\u0131.txt");
   qDebug() << string;

   return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in the above comments, you do need to print to a console that supports these characters for this to work.

Comment: This works for text arguments. When I pass a QString as argument, this doesn't work.     ```QString string1 = "file\u00d6\u00c7\u015e\u0130\u011e\u00dc\u0130\u00e7\u00f6\u015fi\u011f\u00fc\u0131.txt";```      ```QString string2 = QStringLiteral(string);```

Comment: As the name suggests, it's *only* intended for string literals.  So in your example you should have wrapped yours like so: `QString string1 = QStringLiteral("file\u00d6\u00c7\u015e\u0130\u011e\u00dc\u0130\u00e7\u00f6\u015fi\u011f\u00fc\u‌​0131.txt");`

Answer (score 2):

I have just tested this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString s = "file\u00d6\u00c7\u015e\u0130\u011e\u00dc\u0130\u00e7\u00f6\u015fi\u011f\u00fc\u0131.txt";
    qDebug() << s.length();  //Outputs: 22
    qDebug() << s;           //Outputs: fileÖÇŞİĞÜİçöşiğüı.txt
    return a.exec();
}
```

This is with Qt 5.4 on ubuntu, so it looks like your problem is with some OS only.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QTextDocument>

QTextDocument doc;

QString string = "file\u00d6\u00c7\u015e\u0130\u011e\u00dc\u0130\u00e7\u00f6\u015fi\u011f\u00fc\u0131.txt";
doc.setHtml(string);                   // to convert entities to text
QString result = doc.toPlainText();    // result = "fileÖÇŞİĞÜİçöşiğüı.txt"
```

NOT USEFUL if you have a CONSOLE app
QTextDocument needs the GUI module.

Comment: just another way to do it

Comment: QStringLiteral don't use QString as argument, so use this way if you have QString