# external log file as UTF8 and with \r\n

Tags: c++, qt, logging, qml

I have this code:

```cpp
    void myMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &, const QString & msg)
    {
        QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
        QString formattedTime = time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
        QByteArray formattedTimeMsg = formattedTime.toLocal8Bit();

        QString txt;
        switch (type) {
        case QtDebugMsg:
            txt = QString("%1: Debug: %2").arg(formattedTime, msg);
            break;
        case QtWarningMsg:
            txt = QString("%1: Warning: %2").arg(formattedTime, msg);
        break;
        case QtCriticalMsg:
            txt = QString("%1: Critical: %2").arg(formattedTime, msg);
        break;
        case QtFatalMsg:
            txt = QString("%1: Fatal: %2").arg(formattedTime, msg);
        break;
        }
        QFile outFile("debug.log");
        outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);
        QTextStream ts(&outFile);
        ts << txt << endl;
    }
```

which works very well as saving all console logs into the external file debug.log.
However I don't know how to set it to format the file as UTF8 because some of my local special characters cant be read properly when open the file.
And also how do I make new line after each record? It's all in one line 
depends on what application I open the log file - notepad won't show me new lines, notepad++ does, wordpad also don't...)

Thank you very much for your help guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create UTF-8 file in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780507/create-utf-8-file-in-qt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both can be achieved by configuring your text stream:

1. End-of-line terminators will be translated into `"\r\n"` on Windows when the stream is opened as text: `QTextStream ts(&outFile, QIODevice::Text);`
2. Set the codec to write UTF-8: `ts.setCodec("UTF-8");`

Documentation of `QTexStream` is quite good: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html